# How can I recursively delete records using realm.io (Java/Android)?

Tags: java, android, recursion, realm

How can I recursively delete records with one-to-many relationships using realm.io?

For example I have the following nested objects:

```
public class RealmUnit extends RealmObject {
    private int id;
    private RealmList<RealmChapter> chapters;
    public RealmUnit() {
        chapters = new RealmList<>();
}
```

---

```
public class RealmChapter extends RealmObject {
    private int id;
    private RealmList<RealmChapterGoal> chapterGoals;
    public RealmChapter() {
        chapterGoals = new RealmList<>();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class RealmChapterGoal extends RealmObject {
    private String type;
    private String text;
    public RealmChapterGoal() {}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Realm doesn't cascading deletes, but it is on our TODO and is tracked here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1104

So right now your only option is unfortunately a manually bottom-up approach.

```
for(RealmChapter chapter: realmUnit.getChapters) {
 chapter.getChapterGoals().clear();
}

realmUnit.getChapters().deleteAllFromRealm();
realmUnit.deleteFromRealm();
```

There is also a few more work-arounds described here: 
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2717

Comment: removeFromRealm(); has been depreciated, use deleteFromRealm(); instead.